# Throwing bad_exception when calling current_exception()

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

Link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception provides the following description of `current_exception()`:

> If called during exception handling (typically, in a catch clause), captures the current exception object and creates an std::exception_ptr that holds either a copy or a reference to that exception object (depending on the implementation).
>
> ...
>
> If the implementation of this function requires copying the captured exception object and its copy constructor throws an exception, the returned pointer will hold a reference to the exception thrown. If the copy constructor of the thrown exception object also throws, the returned pointer may hold a reference to an instance of std::bad_exception to break the endless loop.

I am trying to find out if the implementation of `current_exception()` in GCC7 copies captured exception object, or just returns the reference to an already existing object. So far, I think that GCC implements the second case. I've tried to check it by executing the following code:

```
class my_copy_exception : public exception
{
  public:
    my_copy_exception () : exception () {}
    my_copy_exception (const my_copy_exception& other) : 
      exception(other) 
      {
        throw my_copy_exception();
      }

    const char* what () const throw() {return "my_copy_exception";}
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw my_copy_exception();
  }
  catch (const exception& e)
  {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
    exception_ptr eptr = current_exception();

    try
    {
      rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& en)
    {
      cout << en.what() << endl;
      exception_ptr eptrn = current_exception();

      cout << (eptr == eptrn) << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
my_copy_exception
my_copy_exception
1
```

Whether it is possible to claim that there is no copying of the exception object? If not, how to make `current_exception()` throw `bad_exception`?

Comment: Why don't you just `my_copy_exception (const my_copy_exception& other) = delete;` ?

Comment: @Superlokkus My intention was to implement endless loop this way. Copy constructor throws exception of the same type. If `bad_exception` is supported by `current_exception()`, it is probably the case where it shall be thrown.

Comment: Well I guess gcc sees that your code is not an endless loop case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about open source software like GCC 7 is that, rather than attempt to reverse engineer what it probably is doing, you can simply go and look at the source code to see exactly what it is doing.

In the case of GCC 7.4, the implementation of `std::current_exception()` can be found in libstdc++, more specifically, in [libsupc++/eh_ptr.cc line 177](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_ptr.cc#L177):

```cpp
std::exception_ptr
std::current_exception() noexcept
{
  __cxa_eh_globals *globals = __cxa_get_globals ();
  __cxa_exception *header = globals->caughtExceptions;

  if (!header)
    return std::exception_ptr();

  // Since foreign exceptions can't be counted, we can't return them.
  if (!__is_gxx_exception_class (header->unwindHeader.exception_class))
    return std::exception_ptr();

  return std::exception_ptr(
    __get_object_from_ambiguous_exception (header));
}
```

The fist couple of lines here just fetch the currently active exception. If there is no active exception or the active exception did not come from this C++ runtime, then it returns an empty `exception_ptr` (see [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/unwind-cxx.h#L343), [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/unwind-cxx.h#L357), [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/unwind-generic.h#L90), [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/unwind-generic.h#L61), [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/eh_throw.cc#L82), [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/eh_throw.cc#L66), and [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/unwind-cxx.h#L262) for the details on how these checks operate). If there is an active exception that did come from the C++ runtime, it [then](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h#L389) [gets](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h#L381) [itself](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h#L233) a pointer to the active exception object and constructs an `exception_ptr`. The `exception_ptr` [constructor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_ptr.cc#L68) it uses simply [increments](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_ptr.cc#L96) the reference counter of the exception object.

Thus, it would seem that libstdc++ exceptions are reference-counted and a copy is never made in the libstdc++ implementation of `std::current_exception()` for GCC 7, which is in accordance with the requirements of the specification and seems to match your observations…